# In rails, is it possible to do a query that returns all the records with a minumum number of characters in a text or string column?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I ask because a thorough Google search returns no clue as to how to do this.

I am trying to pull an example of a column field which is rarely used and is unfortunately littered with newlines and dashes even in empty ones, so I can't just ask for ones that have data. I need to ask for a column that has at least 10-15 characters or something like this. I can also imagine this query being useful for validating pre-existing data. I know about the validator that does this, but I'm not trying to validate, I'm trying to search.
Thanks!

Comment: I doubt activerecord support this out of the box but there should be some way to do it in the DB language. What database are you using?

Comment: Rails supports custom SQL where clauses. You can put there anything you want. What's the problem? You can also retrieve all records and then filter in code to your hearts content. Please be more specific about what you are trying to do. With code snippets preferably.

Comment: PostgreSQL lol must write more text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems ActiveRecord does not support this. But you can do it anyway like (Mysql example)

```
Model.where("CHAR_LENGTH(text_field) = ?", 10)
```

in Postgres the same should work but in documentation it says to use char_length()

---

Also what you could do is on saving the record store the size of the field with a callback

```
before_save {|r| r.text_field_size = r.text_field.size}
```

With this you can now query with that, wich will be DB agnostic.

```
Model.where(text_field_size: 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to write so part of the request in SQL.

For MySQL, use something like :

```
Model.where("CHAR_LENGTH(field_name) >= ?", min_length)
```